# Click on label makes click on radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this : when the user click on the radiobutton label, it will automatically click on the radio button itself. Currently if the user clicks on the label right after the radiobutton, nothing happens, forcing the user to click on the tiny radiobutton itself.

Some people suggested to use the 'for' attribute on the label, but to do so i need to change the 'id' of the second option ; by doing this, the form will post both options as checked, so it won't work in my case.

https://jsfiddle.net/j4qzh544/2/

Here is the html :

```
<form href="#">
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option one" value="1"><label class="radio-label">Option one</label>
    <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option two" value="2"><label class="radio-label">Option two</label>  
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

To achieve this, i'm trying to use Jquery to create a click method on each label with the class 'radio-label', making a click on its radiobutton. Something like the code below, but it's not working :

```
 $('.radio-label').each(function (i) {
    $(this).previous().click();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes) attribute of `<label>`.

> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

```
<label for="option2" class="radio-label">Option two</label>
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option one" value="1"><label for="option1" class="radio-label">Option one</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="option1" data-label="Option two" value="2"><label for="option2" class="radio-label">Option two</label>
```

Comment: This worked, but it if i change the 'id' to 'option2' , when i post the form, it will post both options ; how can i know what option was checked ?

Comment: @delphirules, When `form` is posted it use `name` attribute not `id` and you should check the `value` property of `radio` to check which option was selected.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need any js or jQuery code. Just include `for` attribute inside the `label`. As it's value, provide the `id` of the specified radio button.

```html
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option one" value="1" /><label class="radio-label" for='option1'>Option one</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="option1" data-label="Option two" value="2" /><label class="radio-label" for='option2'>Option two</label>
```

Comment: Oh, nice ! Thanks :D

Comment: Although it worked, if i change the id attribute of the 'option2', when i post the form, both will be posted as both was checked. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `input` tag inside the`label` tag.
Just like this :

```
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option one" value="1">Option one
</label>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option two" value="2">Option two</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [label for](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" data-label="Option one" value="1"><label class="radio-label" for="option1">Option one</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="option" data-label="Option two" value="2"><label class="radio-label" for="option2">Option two</label>
```

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bkhu8eq9/) (no js required)

Comment: Although it worked, if i change the id attribute of the 'option2', when i post the form, both will be posted as both was checked. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the input tag inside the label thatis enough

```html
    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option one" value="1">Option one</label>
    <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" data-label="Option two" value="2">Option two</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any js for this, simply use this

```
<label for="option2" class="radio-label">Option two</label>

<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" data-label="Option one" value="1"><label class="radio-label" for="option1">Option one</label>
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="option" data-label="Option two" value="2"><label class="radio-label" for="option2">Option two</label>
```

Comment: Although it worked, if i change the id attribute of the 'option2', when i post the form, both will be posted as both was checked. How can i fix this ?